# react-native component doesn't re-render after update redux state

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I'm building an application in react-native and I'm using redux. 
I'm using websocket to update my redux state. From a web interface I click a button and it increments a score on my app. What I want to do is display a modal everytime the redux state is updated here is my code :

Websocket.js :

```
import RoutesApp from './constantApi'
import { store } from '../store/configStore'

export function initWebSocketConnection(teamName) {
    var ws = new WebSocket('ws://' + RoutesApp.HostName + '/ws?teamId=' + teamName);

    ws.onopen = () => {
        // connection opened
        // nothing special to do
    };

    ws.onmessage = (e) => {
        // a message was received
        const message = JSON.parse(e.data);
        switch (message.messageType) {
            case 'giveaway/message':
                store.dispatch({type: 'GIVEAWAY', value: message});
                break
        };

        ws.onerror = (e) => {
            // an error occurred
            console.log(e.message);
        };

        ws.onclose = (e) => {
            // connection closed
            console.log(e.code, e.reason);
        };
    };
  }
```

Reducer :

```
const initialState = {
  notification: []
}

const teamPaths = (state = initialState, action) => {
  let nextState
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'GIVEAWAY':
      nextState = {
        ...state,
      }
      nextState.notification.push('Vous avez gagné une charge de pouvoir')
      break
    default:
  }
  return nextState || state
}

export default teamPaths
```

Modal.js

```
lass ModalGeneral extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      modalVisible: false,
    }
  }

  visibleYe(){
    if(this.props.notification.length > 0){
      return !this.state.modalVisible
    }else if(this.props.notification.length === 0){
      return this.state.modalVisible
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Modal
        style={{ justifyContent: 'center' }}
        animationIn="slideInUp"
        animationInTiming={1000}
        animationOutTiming={1000}
        isVisible={this.visibleYe()}
      >
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.titleModal}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>{this.props.notification}</Text>
          </View>
      </Modal>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    notification: state.notification
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ModalGeneral)
```

But When I call my modal component in another component, the modal opens only when the components renders, then everything is like I want, with the message pushed displaying but Why does the redux state update doesn't make the component re render ? I saw a lot of that solution :

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  notification: state.myReducer.notificaion
})
```

replacing with the name of my reducer of course : teamData, but it's not working and throw an error :

```
cannot read property notification of undefined
```

I really really need this and I don't understand the problem, what am I missing ?

[EDIT]

configStore.js

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import teamData from './reducers/teamData'


export const store = createStore(teamData);
```

Comment: how is your store configured?  can you share that code so we can see how the store is structured?

Comment: @Dmase05 I updated my question with the configStore !

Comment: your reducer shows that you push to the notifications array.  you should copy the array and update it: https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns#inserting-and-removing-items-in-arrays

I think since state is referencing the same array, redux doesn't know that there is a state change as it's not comparing the array value but will detect a reference to a new array

Comment: That Works !! Thanks man you saved my life !!